# How to receive external notifications 24/7 without being a Service?

Tags: android

I want my app to receive notifications from an external server,  like Urban Airship ,at all times, but I don't want it to be a Service because that would make it ineligible for app2sd aka installLocation=preferExternal right??

Comment: Could you explain in greater detail what you mean by "receive notifications at all times"?

Comment: That was not a particularly helpful clarification. By "greater detail" I meant a few hundred words, not merely four. Do you even have an idea of how, exactly, you intend to "receive notifications from an external server"? C2DM? Xtify? Urban Airship? WebSockets? Comet? Polling? SMS? Something else?

Comment: For the sake of clarity, Urban Airship would count as "external server" yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want my app to receive notifications from an external server at all times

This runs completely counter to:

> app2sd aka installLocation=preferExternal

If you allow your application to be installed on external storage, your application will not be running when external storage is mounted. You will not receive any push notifications by any means during that time. It will also terminate any running components (e.g., a `Service`) that you may have running at the time the user mounts external storage.

Hence, if you want "to receive notifications from an external server at all times", do not implement `installLocation=preferExternal`, period.

You cite Urban Airship as an example. If you specifically are using Urban Airship, you should be asking your Urban Airship questions on an Urban Airship support board, as they will have much more concrete advice about the use of Urban Airship with `installLocation=preferExternal`.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider reading up on Intent Filters, if that's what you mean by "notifications."